# How to attach a database file with logical name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, connection, connection-string

First of all please refer the screenshot:

[image]

1. What is the use of `Logical name` and why do we use it?
2. I attached the mdf file which is not in sql path. This connection succeeded.
3. Additionally given the logical name, now connections throws the error:

> Error: Unable to open the physical path ""  operation system error 32,
>   Cannot attach the file "" as database ""

I googled for this, but no one suggest the perfect solution.

I tried this in `Administrator mode`, and `Windows authentication`.

Answer (score 0):

On a specific data folder, you cannot have the same .mdf file
But with different .mdf or .ndf file names you can create data files with same names for different databases on a SQL Server instance

Could you please check if your target database, do you have a data file with name "AttachFile" before you do the restore?

Comment: There is no same mdf file for specific data folder when i am attach database file. 
could you please tell why we use logical name?

Comment: A database is formed of database files. The logical name is the datafile name for each data file forming the database. It is unique in a database, but different databases can have the same logical name.   For example, if you create a snapshot of your database, you have to use the same data file name (logical name) but with a different physical file name.    For example:   CREATE DATABASE AttachFileSnapshotDB  
ON  
(NAME = AttachFile,  
FILENAME ='C:\Users\Desktop\db\AttachFile_SS.mdf')  
AS SNAPSHOT OF AttachFile;  
GO